# Unable to add elementary tweaks repo (gpg key timed out)

Tags: release-juno

I just came back to try out elementary os again and went for the most recent version (juno).
I wanted to install the elementary tweaks but adding the repo takes at least 5 minutes to even ask me to press the enter key and after some more time I get the error "Error: retrieving gpg key timed out."

what could be the cause of this? My internet is working btw

Comment: This issue is most likely due to the IPV6 automatically being [enabled] after install. To disable this, follow this guide: [https://itsfoss.com/disable-ipv6-ubuntu-linux/][1] After completing this guide it shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! I only needed to disable IPV 6 (why would you need it anyway?)